# Using jQuery to Create True and False Questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build a questionnaire. See below.

http://cl.ly/image/1W2M3J2z2q2E

http://cl.ly/image/2m461g200b0X

This is what I've got in my code, and it works just fine but as you can see, it gets incredibly long after just two questions. What is the best way to condense this code, so that I do not repeat myself so many times.

```
// find all anchor tag and prevent default behavior
$('.questions').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

var ques1 = $('#question1'),
    q1 = $('.question1'),
    q1True = $('.question1-true').hide(),
    q1False = $('.question1-false').hide();

var ques2 = $('#question2'),
    q2 = $('.question2').hide(),
    q2True = $('.question2-true').hide(),
    q2False = $('.question2-false').hide();

(function () {
    // click button false
    $('#question1 .btn-false').on('click', function(){
        q1.hide();
        q1True.fadeIn();
    });
    // click button true
    $('#question1 .btn-true').on('click', function(){
        q1.hide();
        q1False.fadeIn();
    });
    // click previous button
    $('#question1 .prev').on('click', function(){
        q1True.hide();
        q1False.hide();
        q1.show();
    });
    // click next button
    $('#question1 .next').on('click', function(){       
        ques1.hide();
        q2.show();
    }); //end question1

    // begin question 2
    $('#question2 .btn-false').on('click', function(){
        ques2.show();
        q2.hide();
        q2True.show();
    });

    $('#question2 .btn-true').on('click', function(){
        ques2.show();
        q2.hide();
        q2False.show();
    });
})();
```

Comment: The best way is to try and build it. We expect code in questions that ask for code. When you have it come back, explain what didn't work and people might help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you an idea:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/AzAQeto/3/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="QA">

  <div id="qDIV">    
    <h2></h2>
    <button>False</button>
    <button>True</button>
  </div>

  <div id="response">
     <p></p>
     <button id="prev">Back</button>
     <button id="next">Next</button>
     <button id="score">Score</button>
  </div>

</div>

<pre></pre>
```

Let's now create an Array of object literals to store data:

```
var questionnaire = [
  {
    "question" : "The Earth is round.",
    "response" : "The Earth is round!",  
    "correct"  : 1    // 0=False, 1=True
  },
  {
    "question" : "The 'cravat' is originally from France.",
    "response" : "The 'cravat' is from Croatia!",
    "correct"  : 0
  },
  {
    "question" : "Is Java == JavaScript?",
    "response" : "It's a different language.",
    "correct"  : 0
  } // Add comma and more objects.
];
```

This way we can always keep track of the values and inject at every stage an user answer into our current question object.

```
var $qDIV     = $('#qDIV'),
    $rDIV     = $('#response'),
    $qH2      = $("h2",     $qDIV),
    $answer   = $("button", $qDIV),
    $response = $("p",      $rDIV),
    tot       = questionnaire.length,
    c         = 0; // Current Q array counter 

function QandA( idx ){  
   $qDIV.fadeTo(600,1); 
   $rDIV.hide();  
   var currQ = questionnaire[c];   // The Object literal from Array
   var isCorrect = currQ.correct;  // 0 or 1?
   var answerIsCorrect = idx==isCorrect; // (compare values) Returns boolean 
   var resp = answerIsCorrect ? "Great!" : "Wrong!";
   currQ.answer = idx;             // Put user answer into object (0 or 1)
   $qH2.text( (c+1) +'. '+ currQ.question );
   $response.text( resp +' '+ currQ.response );
}
QandA();

$answer.click(function(){   
    var idx = $answer.index(this); // 0 or 1  (get button index)
    QandA( idx );
    $rDIV.fadeTo(600,1);
    $qDIV.hide();
    console.log( JSON.stringify(questionnaire, null, 2) ); // TEST ONLY
});

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
    c = this.id=='next' ? ++c : c ; // advance or repeat Question
    QandA();
    $('#next').toggle(c<tot-1);
    $('#score').toggle(c>=tot-1);
});

$('#score').click(function(){
  $('pre').text( JSON.stringify(questionnaire, null, 2) ); // TEST
  c = 0; // reset questionnary to first question
  QandA(); // Restart
});
```

---

### Previous answer:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/APAmete/1/edit)**

having this trivial HTML:

```
<div id="QA">    
  <h2></h2>
  <span id="buttons"></span>
  <p>Points : <span>0</span></p>
</div>
```

Let's create an array of object literals like:

```
var questionnaire = [

  {
    "question" : "The earth is...",
    "valid"    : 1, // indicates the correct array number, use 0, 1...
    "buttons"  : ["A cube", "Round"],
    "answers"  : [ "Ohh, c'mon...", "You got it! It's round!"]  
  },
  {
    "question" : "The Cravat is originally from:",
    "valid"    : 0,
    "buttons"  : ["Croatia", "France", "Germany"],
    "answers"  : [ "Great", "Wrong, it's from Croatia!", "Wrong... Sorry"]  
  },
  {
    "question" : "Is Java == JavaScript?",
    "valid"    : 0, 
    "buttons"  : ["False", "True"],
    "answers"  : ["Exatcly!", "Ohh, c'mon..."]
  } // add comma and more Object literals...

];
```

In the above you can create as many possible buttons and answers you want. jQuery will create the buttons out of the needed object Array. Than you set a `valid` pointer to tell the questionnaire logic which of the answers index is the correct one `using 0, 1, 2...`.
After jQ creates our buttons, on a button click you can retrieve it's index and target the needed answer out of your object literal, and to determine the points see if the clicked button index matches your `valid` value.
As you can see you can advance your questions by incrementing a counter variable after every button click (we'll call `qc`):

```
var $qa       = $('#QA'),
    $question = $("h2", $qa),
    $buttons  = $("#buttons", $qa),
    $points   = $("p>span",$qa),
    questionnaireLength = questionnaire.length, // How many Q?
    qc        = 0,                              // Current Question counter
    points    = 0;                              // Current points

function QandA(){

  var quest = questionnaire[qc],
      question = quest.question,
      validIdx = quest.valid,
      btns     = quest.buttons,
      answer   = quest.answers;

  $question.text( question );

  if(qc >= questionnaireLength){
    return alert("game over");
  }

  // generate buttons with text:
  $buttons.empty();
  for(var i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
    $buttons.append("<button>"+ btns[i] +"</button>");
  }

  // Retrieve generated buttons
  var $btn = $("button", $buttons);

  // Assign click
  $btn.one('click', function(){  
    var idx = $btn.index(this); // get button index
    alert("(valid idx is: "+ validIdx +" Clicked button idx: "+ idx +")");
    alert("Game says: "+ answer[idx] );
    points += (idx === parseInt(validIdx, 10) ? 5 : -5);
    $points.text( points );
    // Next question
    qc++; QandA();  // increment question counter and set new game
  });

}
QandA(); // Start game
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is some killer stuff!!..I think this might be an overkill. All questions are based on a true and false and nothing is being stored. Simply, if you click true or false, it shows you the correct answer along with with the previous and next buttons. When you click next or previous it simply shows you the next question or the previous question and hides the answer and the process is repeated all over again.

Comment: @user3128136 Ok, even simpler. What's the purpose of having `prev` and `next` buttons?

Comment: @user3128136 how you keep track of the score? How you keep track of anything? By just leaving a comment without trying to implement my suggestions... do you have an actual question? Currently, from the code you provided in you Q., your questionnaire usability is round to `0`

Comment: The purpose of the prev and next button is to show the question along with the true and false button. like the above two screenshots I included. There is no score, its not a game, just simply a show and hide of the question and answer.